# Why does my php login script work in Chrome, but not in FireFox or Edge?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a php login based on mysql table. It's all working fine w/in Chrome, however in both Firefox and Edge, when I type a username and password I am just brought back to the login page. (with correct OR incorrect credentials)

Here is my php code..

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$sel_user = $con->prepare("SELECT id, username, pass, gid FROM employees WHERE gid!=4 AND username=?");
$sel_user->execute([$uname]);
$check_user = $sel_user->fetch();
if(count($check_user)>0 && password_verify($pass, $check_user['pass'])) {
    $_SESSION['username']=$check_user['username'];

    header("Location: xadmin.php" );
    exit;
}

else {

    echo "<script>alert('Email or password is not correct')</script>";
}};?>
```

Here is the html form..

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#3B3B3B" height ="35" class="BodyTxtB" align="center">Administrator Login</td></tr>
            <tr height="20"><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="BodyTxtB" align="center">Username</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="BodyTxtB" align="center"><input type="text" class="BodyTxtBC" name="uname" required="required"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="20"><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="BodyTxtB" align="center">Password</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="BodyTxtB" align="center"><input type="password" class="BodyTxtBC" name="pass" required="required"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="20"><td></td></tr>
            <tr height="35"><td align="center"><input type="image" src="images/btn_login.jpg" name="login" value="Login"/></td></tr>
            <tr height="20"><td></td></tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>
   </form>
```

Here is the validation from xadmin.php

```
<?php session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
header("Location: login.php?e=access_denied");
exit();
}
?>
```

Does anyone know what could be causing the issue?

**UPDATE:** Although not relevant to the original issue or provided answers, I have updated this post to fix the issue's of mysql injection and password encryption

Comment: Stop sorting passwords in plain text!

Comment: I am still in testing and not worried about plain text password. Please stay on topic in regards to the question

Comment: `session_start()` missing `;` for it. Voted to close as a typo.

Comment: @craisondigital Let's be honest, you were never going to go back and add it. You just didn't consider security enough when building this. Security is baked in from the beginning. It isn't here and probably was never going to be.

Comment: @Fred -ii- the typo has been fixed. that is not what is causing the problem

Comment: @JohnConde you are 100% wrong. I am not here to argue with you.

Comment: Could you please add the authentication validation code in xadmin.php?

Comment: Holy mother of ignorance.

Comment: check for errors then, you're not doing that. you also need to `exit;` on header. Plus, `<img>` does not count as a POST array; use an `<input>` and submit type. Edit: @CD001 which is what he/she wrote below.

Comment: Do FF/Edge pass through the `name` with `<input type="image" ... />` - I'm pretty sure it just passes through some x/y co-ordinates...

Comment: @Melanef I added the validation from xadmin.php

Comment: If you'd do any proper code indentation, you would have noticed a parse error. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php in turn, choking your script entirely. You've a misplaced brace.

Comment: start it step by step , type a simple input and a simple validation page then add anything else

Comment: @CD001 you are correct!! and also  Changing type to "submit" has solved the issue.  So is their a way to make the submit button an image? In any case, if you put this as an answer, i will mark it complete.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: [which is what I wrote before that...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794742/why-does-my-php-login-script-work-in-chrome-but-not-in-firefox-or-edge?noredirect=1#comment66882601_39794742) not retracting my vote to close.

Comment: @craisondigital change an input submit 's appearance using CSS

Comment: Sorry, @Fred -ii-  I am bad at copying the code to stack overflow. It is indented correctly in my page.  Changing the input type to "submit" has solved the issue.

Comment: which is what I first said. Anyway... he said, she said doesn't matter to me for an answer, it's just to set the record straight ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- what did you mean "you also need to exit; on header." Should it look like this? "header("Location: xadmin.php" ) exit;"?

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: Thank you @Jay Blanchard I look forward to reading the docs you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox/Edge don't pass through the `name` of `<input type="image" ... />`

If you do a `print_r($_POST)` and submit the form with Firefox you'll get:

```
Array
(
    [login_x] => 0
    [login_y] => 0
)
```

Do the same thing with Chrome, however:

```
Array
(
    [login_x] => 8
    [login_y] => 8
    [login] => Login
)
```

... and there you have it.

You could pass through login as a hidden form field:

```
<input type="image" src="images/btn_login.jpg" />
<input type="hidden" name="login" value="Login" />
```

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="login" value="Login" />` hidden? that should be `submit`.

Comment: Nah `<input type="image" ... />` is a `submit` button - it just applies a graphic to it.